# Custom validation for each field django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model like this:

```
TYPES = (('hi', 'hi'), ('hello', 'hello'))
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=255) # hi
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255) # hello
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=TYPES)
```

As you can see now, every fields are mandatory. What I want to achieve is the following:

`if kind == 'hi':` make `address` not mandatory and `if kind == 'hello'` make `phonenumber` not mandatory. How can I override the model validation for this? And Is something like this can be achieved via `getattr` and `setattr`?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Comment: Also: why using two different text fields if only one kind can be selected ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: So I should write validation for every attribute? I have more than 10 attributes for this model. The `different text fields` are just an example.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Can't I do something like: `def clean(self): if self.kind == 'hi: self.address.__property__.blank = True?'`

Answer (score 0):

You can just overwrite the save()

```
class Test(modesl.Model):
    ## .....
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ....
        if kind == 'hi':
             self.adress = "what you want"
        #.....
        super(Test, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```